# Dropdown picker selection should be empty when adding forms dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just want to add a form dynamically. When clicking on `addAdvice()` a new form should be added. The issue is to clear the previously selected values of the dropdown. The description text is updating fine for each form but the dropdowns are changing to `form1` when changing for `form2`.

```
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.fixToText}>
        <Text style={styles.titles}>Unit:</Text>
        <Text style={styles.titles}>Date: {date}</Text>
      </View>
  {adviceList.map((advice, i) => {
  return (
      <View key={i}>
        <Text style={styles.adviceHeader}>Advice{i+1}</Text>
        <DropDownPicker
          defaultNull
          placeholder="Select a Category"
          open={open}
          value={category}
          items={items}
          searchable={true}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          setValue={setCategory}
          setItems={setItems}
          listMode="MODAL"
          modalProps={{ animationType: "fade", width: "50%", height: "100%" }}
          modalContentContainerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            width: "100%",
            height: "50%",
          }}
          onChangeValue={ (value) => onCategoryChange(value, i)}
        />
        {/* <Text>
          {console.log(selectedValue)}
          {console.log(data)}
        </Text> */}
        <Separator />
        <DropDownPicker
          defaultNull
          placeholder="Select a Sub Category"
          open={open1}
          value={subCategory}
          items={data}
          searchable={true}
          setOpen={setOpen1}
          setValue={setSubCategory}
          // setItems={setItems1}
          listMode="MODAL"
          modalProps={{ animationType: "fade", width: "50%", height: "100%" }}
          modalContentContainerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            width: "100%",
            height: "50%",
          }}
          onChangeValue={ (value) => onSubCategoryChange(value, i)}
        />

        <Separator />

        {/* Resolution Box  */}
        <View style={styles.textAreaContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textArea}
            placeholder="Enter Advice here"
            placeholderTextColor="grey"
            maxLength={300}
            multiline={true}
            onChangeText={ (value) => {
              setDescription(value)
              onDescriptionChange(value, i)
            }
            }
          />

      {adviceList.length !== 1 && 
        <Button
          title="Remove"
          onPress={() => removeAdvice(i)} />}
        </View>
        <Separator />

      
        {adviceList.length - 1 === i &&
        <Button
          title="Add resolutions"
          color="#0eb34b"
          onPress={addAdvice}
        />}
        {/* <View style={styles.fixToText}>
          <Button
            title="Save for later"
            onPress={() => console.log("Save for later is clicked ")}
          /> */}

     
        </View>
  );
  })}
       <Button
            title="Submit "
            onPress={() => {
              handleClick();
            }}
          />
  </View>
 )

var selectedCategory, selectedSubCategory, selectedDescription;
    const list = [...adviceList];
    const onCategoryChange = (value, i) => {
      selectedCategory = value;
      list[i]["category"] = selectedCategory;
      selectedCategory = "";
      console.log("cat value", list[i]["category"] );
    };

    const onSubCategoryChange = (value, i) => {
      selectedSubCategory = value;
      console.log("subcat value", value);
      list[i]["subCategory"] = selectedSubCategory;
      selectedSubCategory = "";
    };

    const onDescriptionChange = (value, i) => {
      selectedDescription = value;
      console.log("desc value", value);
      console.log("The i is", i);
      // selectedDescription = value;
      
      console.log("The list is: ", list);
      list[i]["description"] = selectedDescription;
      selectedDescription = "";
      // list[index][value] = value;
      setAdviceList(list);
    };
  
    // handle click event of the Remove button
    const removeAdvice = index => {
      const list = [...adviceList];
      list.splice(index, 1);
      setAdviceList(list);
    };
  
    // handle click event of the Add button
    const addAdvice = () => {
      category = '';
      subCategory = '';
      setAdviceList([...adviceList, { category: "", subCategory: "", description: "" }]);
    };
```

To put it simpler: when clicking the `AddAdvice` button the previous value of the dropdown needs to be flushed.

```
<DropDownPicker
          defaultNull
          placeholder="Select a Category"
          value={adviceList[i].category}
          items={items}
          searchable={true}
          setValue={setCategory}
          setItems={setItems}
          listMode="MODAL"
          modalProps={{ animationType: "fade", width: "50%", height: "100%" }}
          modalContentContainerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            width: "100%",
            height: "50%",
          }}
          onChangeValue={ (value) => onCategoryChange(value, i)}
        />
```

Comment: Your logic is too complicated and hard to follow. Can you try to simplify your question and code to what will help you solve your problem? Screenshots/diagrams will also help

Comment: @saameer, just want to know how to set dropdownpicker value to "" on addAdvice